# SCP from Remote Server to Windows Local Machine

Tags: linux, windows, scp

I am trying to move a file from a server to my windows machine. The following code is what appears.

```
$ scp username@blah.edu:/blah/blah/BclPipeline.py ./C:\Users\username\Python_Programming
```

Everytime that I run it, it asks for my password and then prints the name of the file BclPipline.py onto the screen:

```
Password:
BclPipeline.py
                                                 100% 7148     7.0KB/s   00:00
```

Yet, when I go looking for the file on my computer I cannot find it.

Comment: Are you running the `scp` command from Cygwin? What is the current directory when you run that command? In Linux, `./` means 'from my current directory' so it might be getting stored in the directory with a filename of `C:\Users\username\Python_Programming`.